# Cox proportional hazards - risk increase for a given increase in predictor variable

Tags: r, standard-error, cox-model

I am trying to assess the predictive properties of a variable for an event. The following output from R, describes the model:

```
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, event) ~ A, data = population)

  n= 50, number of events= 27 

           coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z Pr(>|z|)  
A       0.05096   1.05228  0.02149 2.371   0.0177 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

        exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
A           1.052     0.9503     1.009     1.098

Concordance= 0.64  (se = 0.062 )
Rsquare= 0.098   (max possible= 0.974 )
Likelihood ratio test= 5.15  on 1 df,   p=0.02327
Wald test            = 5.62  on 1 df,   p=0.01774
Score (logrank) test = 5.67  on 1 df,   p=0.0173
```

From what I get there is an increase in risk of 5.2% for every increase in A of 0.021. If I would like to express risk as an increase in A of 0.01, would I simply do the following?

```
exp(coef) = 2.149nd root of 1.052 = 1.024
CI = 2.149nd root of 1.009 and 1.098 = [1.004; 1.044]
p is of course unchanged
```